# Sorting an array effecting previous arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array to find the mean of it. After finding the median I'm looking to continue using the array.  When using the code,

```
            double[] views, viewssorted;
            views = new double[] {9.0, 1111.0,  2.0 };
            viewssorted = views;
            Array.Sort(viewssorted);
```

both my `viewssorted` and `views` arrays get sorted. How do I make it so that only `viewssorted` gets sorted?

Comment: By creating a copy of the array.

Comment: You don't have two arrays; you have two variables that point to the same array.

Comment: How does sorting an array help you in finding the mean?

Comment: it was meant to be median

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using

```
viewssorted = views;
```

`viewssorted` and `views` are references to the same array. Thus, any change in the first will be reflected in the second.

You should use [Array.Clone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone(v=vs.110).aspx) to make a copy of the array.

```
viewssorted = (double[]) views.Clone();;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that arrays are essentially classes and as such reference types. A reference type does not hold a value but rather points to an area in your memory.

When you write `viewssorted = views;` you are assigning the same reference you have in views to viewssorted. They are essentially the same object referenced by two variables.

To create a copy of the array, but with the same internal references (in your case the same double values), use `Array.Clone()`.

This would be

```
viewssorted = (double[])Array.Clone(views);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are reference types in C#, that's why they both sort.

You can do

```
views.CopyTo(viewssorted)
```

Or

```
viewssorted = views.Clone()
```